# Grouping in Windows Functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following columns:

a. year_month (timestamp in monthly buckets)
b. item_id: (sku)
c. keycust4: (customer)
d. frcst_qty: (shipped qty)

I want to find the following:

1. The sum of frcst_qty per month;
2. The average frcst_qty by item_id and keycust4 across months
3. The standard deviation.

I am using the query below.

```sql
    SELECT   [year_month]
    ,[item_id]
    ,[keycust4]
    ,SUM([frcst_qty])
    ,AVG( [frcst_qty] ) OVER ( PARTITION BY [item_id], [keycust4] )
    ,STDEV (SUM([frcst_qty]) ) OVER ( PARTITION BY [item_id], [keycust4] )
    FROM [aws_stage]
    GROUP BY [year_month]
    ,[item_id]
    ,[keycust4]
```

I don't have a problem when I query the sum of the forecast quantity and/or the standard deviation. However, when I add the average aggregation, I get an error message stating that frcst_qty (which is a value) needs to be in an aggregate or a group by.

What is the best way to get the average without adding the frcst_qty to the group by?

Below is a sample of my data:

```
year_month  item_id        keycust4            frcst_qty
2020-01-01  105.09050   Customer A - PNW          253
2020-01-01  105.09050   Customer A - PNW          180
2020-02-01  105.09050   Customer A - PNW          383
2020-02-01  105.09051   Customer A - PNW          94
2020-02-01  105.09050   Customer A - PNW          54
2020-02-01  105.09050   Customer A - PNW          108
2020-03-01  105.09050   Customer A - PNW          311
2020-03-01  105.09050   Customer A - PNW          390
2020-05-01  105.09050   Customer A - PNW          49
2020-06-01  105.09051   Customer A - PNW          254.25
2020-07-01  105.09050   Customer A - PNW          296
2020-08-01  105.09050   Customer A - PNW          602
```

Comment: You say you want average frcst_qty by item_id and keycust4 across months. Then why do you need the over clause for your avg? It''s already grouped by those 3 columns

Comment: @Dumbledore - I have multiple records for each sku/customer iteration per month. Average is giving me the average of unique orders per period, rather than the average total value across all year_month combinations.

Comment: @DaleK Sample data added above

Comment: @satdaya Can you add sample output for that data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you want:

```
SELECT [year_month], [item_id], [keycust4],
       SUM([frcst_qty]),
       AVG( SUM([frcst_qty]) ) OVER ( PARTITION BY [item_id], [keycust4] ),
       STDEV (SUM([frcst_qty]) ) OVER ( PARTITION BY [item_id], [keycust4] )
FROM [aws_stage]
GROUP BY [year_month], [item_id], [keycust4];
```

That is, this takes the average of the summed amount for the year, month, item, and customer.